# Highcharts - Positioning the legend (left and right/x and y)

Tags: javascript, highcharts

My Highcharts solutions give the user the option to control which series are showed at any one point. Because of the amount of series available, I am extending the functionality to checkboxes rather than just add them all on initiation and hide the majority initially as this would make the legend huge.

I would like to overlay a button on the chart to make it look integrated. This gives no problems in itself as I can give a negative value to `legend.x` to move it to make room for the button. However, this then poses a problem when more series are programmatically added, as the legend maintains its original width and I lose some options off to the side when there are too many.

This is a stripped down fiddle of my problem: https://jsfiddle.net/paLoxcy3/. This is a relevant snippet:

```
legend: {
   align: "right",
   x: -100
}
```

It's worth adding here the graph needs to maintain a responsive width, hence I cannot just add a `width`. As an aside, were I do to this (and indeed when the series names do eventually drop a line in my current fiddle), they then become left aligned which is not desired.

I've had a good play around with the options of `legend` but at this point assume the only solution to effectively add `padding-right` to the legend holder is to use `chart.events.load` and `chart.events.redraw` to somehow do it manually? It's a bit annoying as the options to add `marginTop` and 
`marginBottom` exist but not `marginLeft` and `marginRight`.

Any help much appreciated! Shortcut to docs is [here](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend) to save some time :)

Comment: Hi, Thank you for information about this problem. I think that was some small issue in renderItem function. Here you can see how it will work when I have changed this function: https://jsfiddle.net/paLoxcy3/1/

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for your help and for already logging the bug on Github :)

Comment: Happy to read that my example helped you :) I have posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this problem is connected with small issue in Highcharts legend.renderItem function. As a workaround you can change if statement responsible for moving item to another line. Here you can see how this statement looks in code:

```
// if the item exceeds the width, start a new line
        if (horizontal && legend.itemX - initialItemX + itemWidth >
                (widthOption || (chart.chartWidth - 2 * padding - initialItemX - options.x))) {
            legend.itemX = initialItemX;
            legend.itemY += itemMarginTop + legend.lastLineHeight + itemMarginBottom;
            legend.lastLineHeight = 0; // reset for next line (#915, #3976)
        }
```

And Here you can see how I have changed this statement:

```
  // if the item exceeds the width, start a new line
        if (horizontal && legend.itemX - initialItemX + itemWidth >
                (widthOption || (chart.chartWidth - 2 * padding - initialItemX - ((options.align === 'right') ? (-options.x) : options.x)))) {
            legend.itemX = initialItemX;
            legend.itemY += itemMarginTop + legend.lastLineHeight + itemMarginBottom;
            legend.lastLineHeight = 0; // reset for next line (#915, #3976)
        }
```

Here you can find Github topic connected with this issue: 
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5443

And here you can see chart with my workaround:
https://jsfiddle.net/paLoxcy3/2/

Best regards.